# JavaScript Focus() on Element ID with Floating Navigation Bar?

Tags: javascript

On form validation, to prompt the user to fill out the required fields.

The usual;

```
document.getElementById("idHere").focus();
```

When dealing with floating navigation bars at the top of the screen, this doesn't always work, mainly when the element you want to focus on is the first one, it hides behind the floating navigation.

Is there a handy solution to nudge the Focus down a set number of pixels to make sure this takes into account the size of the navigation menu?

Comment: Can you create fiddle for this?

Comment: It would be useful if you could show the HTML/CSS of your navigation bar.

Comment: How is this related to focus? The input would already be covered by the "navigation bar" when it has no focus, right?

Comment: Give me a minute, will create the fiddle

Comment: It's a floating bar covering the input. The browser doesn't know it's covered and so doesn't scroll far enough.

@Michael The solution is to scroll a little more on focus. I've solved this problem in the past using jQuery, would posting that be useful to you?

Comment: Before calling `focus()`, you could first scroll to the top with `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`. Does that resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a scroll function to your function or the element onFocus.
it could be like this :

```
window.scrollTo( window.scrollX , document.getElementById("idHere").scrollTop + 80 );
```

Comment: This is what I need, although it doesn't seem to work. The next line is `return false` to ensure the submitted form doesn't work, although it appears to ignore that when I add in this line of code. Any ideas?

Comment: @MichaelCropper Fixed it . ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution as a jQuery function. You use it by passing a selector by whatever elements you want to have the behavior. For example `bindFocusScroll('input, select');`

```
function bindFocusScroll(selector){
  var navHeight = 192;
  var padding = 25;
  $(selector).on('focus', function() {
    try {
      var elemTop = $(this).offset().top;
      var maxVisible = $(document).scrollTop() + navHeight;
      if (elemTop < maxVisible) {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: elemTop - navHeight - padding }, 250);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error: " + e);
    }
  });
}
```

If you don't need it to animate or be smart you can just use Sasan's answer. I can help you recreate this answer in vanilla JS if needed as well.

Comment: jQuery is perfect. This looks exactly like what I'm after, just struggling to get this working. I've added the function to the JS on the page, then where I used to have the code for, `document.getElementById("idHere").focus();`, I've added in the, `bindFocusScroll('input, select');`, but I'm not sure what to put inside the quotes ' ' which I guess is why I'm not getting this to work. Have I implemented that incorrect?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this right away. The problem is that you replaced your focus command. You still need that to do the focus. The `bindFocusScroll` just makes it so that when you do focus it will do the extra scrolly bit. The advantage of this is that if a user focuses the element (with tab for example) they'll get the same behavior.